# Resolution Problem at Install

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, display-resolution

I download the last version of ubuntu and mount  the iso to disk on key to make dual boot install.
I boot the install but I cant continue.
Its see like the resolution is go over 2 screen but i  dont see the window of the install.
I dont have 2  screen that connected.
How I can change the resolution of the install?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Roey, I had the same problem when I purchased my new AMD 64 bit HP.  I have run Ubuntu for almost 10 years.  The problem comes with "wide screen resolution".  If you had an older computer like I did, a laptop with a screen resolution of 4:3 and you were running nothing higher that Ubuntu V12.xx, no problem.  But when I tried to upgrade to v14.04 i had the same problem.  The only solution I could find was to go to V15.10 BETA TEST!  Definately not good, but it works, FULL OF BUGS.  My screen resolution is Wide Screen; 16:9.

I have gone to the Ubuntu forums for a long time, lots of other people are experiencing the same problem.

BUT: 15.10 works if you are willing to live with the problems.  A major problem is that 15.10 does not allow you to set the partition sizes, it does that automatically and gives you no control.

The second problem with 15.10, when it installs a new Linux Kernel, it does not delete the older kernels, so your boot partiton rapidly becomes full.

I am not good at working at the terminal level.  I can not delete the older versions of the kernel, therefore I Can NOT get any more current updates, fixes or patches.

I just now tried to install the BETA 2, V16.04, no luck.  I have tried to get help from the Ubuntu community to no avail.

You will be able to run V15.10 BETA Test, if you are willing to live with the bugs.  I am waiting for the final V16.04 LTS, secure, supported version due to realease this April 21.  I hope that helps both of us.

Comment: Ok , you are right. My Computer is old but I think he still strong. I tried now to enter this install in my new laptop and here there is no this problem. so , where i can get the ubuntu V12.xx ?

Comment: Update - I installed the 12.04 LTS and after the install finish I run update to 14.04 and its work fine.